# Entity Framework ManyToMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Всем привет. Есть некая сущность, предположим что это Person, которая имеет отношение многие ко многим **сама с собой**.

```
class Person  
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Person> Friends { get; set; }  

    public Person()
    {
        this.Friends = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Конфигурация EF для данной сущности выглядит следующим образом

```
class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Friends).WithMany();
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы:

```
EFContext context = new EFContext();

// Создали первого человека.
Person  p_1 = new Person();
p_1.Name = "Вася";

// Создали второго человека.
Person  p_2 = new Person();
p_2.Name = "Петя";

// Добавили второго человека в друзья к первому. 
p_1.Friends.Add(p_2); 

// Добавили в контекст, сохранили в БД.
// Все люди успешно сохранились в БД.
context.Students.Add(p_1);
context.SaveChanges();

// ---------------------------------
// Здесь начинается самое интересное.
// ---------------------------------

// Начинаем получать людей:    

// Получаем первого человека из БД.
var first = context.People.First(p => p.Name == "Вася");
first.Friends.Count(); // 1 сущность. У Васи есть в друзьях Петя.

// Получаем второго человека из БД. 
var second = context.People.First(p => p.Name == "Петя");

// Смотрим сколько у Пети друзей.
second.Friends.Count(); // 0 друзей. У Пети нет Васи в друзьях. 
                        // Хотя там логично ожидать увидеть Васю.
```

Добавлю, такая проблема наблюдается, только когда сущность имеет отношение многие ко многим сама с собой. Собственно, как ее решить, т.е. как сконфигурировать EF так, чтобы при обращении к Пете, EF автоматом подтягивало и Васю.

Comment: для этого нужна промежуточная таблица

Comment: Промежуточную таблицу EF и сам создавать умеет - но проблема не в ней.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема в том, что связь не является симметричной. Симметричную связь силами EF сделать невозможно - просто потому что такая связь не имеет нормального отображения на схему БД. Возможно, вам надо пересмотреть вашу схему БД.

Можно добавить в сущность `Student` еще одну коллекцию, которая будет вторым концом для связи. В таком случае, в `OnModelCreating` будет написано что-то вроде

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasMany(p => p.Students).WithMany(p => p.Students2);
```

В таком случае, после добавления Васи в Петину коллекцию `Students` Петя автоматически появится в Васиной коллекции `Students2`.

Разумеется, исходную задачу это не решает. Я лишь показал, что понимаю под "несимметричностью" связи.

PS Откуда такое название для коллекции - `Students`? Оно не говорит ровным счетом ничего про то, что именно в ней хранится.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, подобные варианты решения задачи я видел, но к сожаление они мне не очень нравились, думал, что возможно существуют какие-то варианты конфигурации EF без введения дополнительной коллекции. P.S. По поводу "Откуда такое название для коллекции" не обращайте на это внимание, такое имя дано только в качестве демонстрации проблемы и не более.

Comment: Какие такие "варианты решения"? Я их не предлагал. Чтобы предложить вариант решения, надо знать больше про вашу задачу.

Comment: Да подобных задач может быть много. Предположим, есть человек, у человека есть друзья. Например, если Петя друг Васи, то логично предположить что и Вася друг Пети и т.д. P.S. Свой вопрос обновил.

Comment: Если посмотреть на соцсети - то там "друг" не является симметричным отношением. Один человек может добавить в друзья второго - а второй может отказаться добавлять первого.

Comment: > Если посмотреть на соцсети... Если один человек откажется добавлять другого, то никто ни у кого в друзьях не будет.

Comment: Будет. Только обычно такое отношение называется "подписчик" или "последователь". В БД хранятся именно они, а "друг" - это отношение вычислимое, в БД напрямую не хранится.